# Which is the name of the Azure VideoIndexer apikey parameter?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-video-indexer

Today I am facing a problem:

I am trying to automate an azure logic app deployment with a VideoIndexer service from Azure, using Terraform but it ask me for a parameter called API Key (on the web side).
The official documentation is this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-video-analyzer/video-analyzer-for-media-docs/logic-apps-connector-tutorial

But I cannot find the name of the apiKey parameter (and no, it isn't apiKey)

Anyone could help here? And for help me to avoid doing a question like that: how can I check an Apiconnection to see which parameters are registered?

Maybe this example could help you (I didn't find the answer there, but maybe you have better eyes than me): https://www.returngis.net/2021/04/como-desplegar-azure-logic-apps-con-terraform/

Answer (score 1):

The apiKey for the videoindexer is named 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key'

See also the example on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-video-analyzer/video-analyzer-for-media-docs/video-indexer-use-apis